# How can I issue the 'prompt' command from a batch file in a Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I want to specify a custom command prompt when I launch a console.  E.g Windows cmd.exe.

I am using the /K command line parameter in the shortcut that launches the console:

`%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /K myprompt.bat`

myprompt.bat contains the following lines:

```
prompt $d $t$_$p$g
cls
```

When I issue the `prompt` command manually in the console window, the prompt appears like this:

[image]

However, if I execute myprompt.bat (either manually, or using the /K command line parameter), I receive the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the batch file in notepad, and try another "encoding" option when you save it.

Comment: +1 The batch file has been saved as Unicode instead of ANSI.

Comment: It is saved as Unicode. I also tried Unicode big endian, and UTF-8, but I get the same results.

Comment: I've ran into a similar problem before. I believe I ended up using the command line "Edit" and copying the script in there and saving it with a different file name.

Comment: @Weltonv3.51: As my previous comment suggests, did you save as ANSI and try? You don't even need to create a new file. Just use Save As in Notepad with the same name but ANSI encoding.

Comment: @DonNickel: If this is 64-bit Windows there's no Edit available anymore.